# Getting a 500 error on response when using the Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm getting some errors when using the Fine Uploader library and can't figure out why.

Here's what's happening. This is the code I'm using on my page:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("fineUploader"),
    request: {
        endpoint: "mybucket.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/wp-content/themes/zone/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint.php"
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: "/wp-content/themes/zone/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint.php?success"
    },
    objectProperties: {
        key: "filename"
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: "/wp-content/themes/zone/success.html"
    },
    cors: {
        expected: true
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
});
```

This code is uploading the file to S3 but I'm getting an error on the page:

In the UI of the uploader, I get an error message stating "Upload Failed" in the red box.

In the Developer Console, I get:

```
POST http://comain.dev/wp-content/themes/zone/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint.php?success 500 (Internal Server Error)sendRequest @ s3.fine-uploader.js:3936prepareToSend @ s3.fine-uploader.js:4055send @ s3.fine-uploader.js:4106qq.extend.sendSuccessRequest @ s3.fine-uploader.js:9042(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:8184(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:702qq.nonTraditionalBasePrivateApi._onComplete @ s3.fine-uploader.js:8188qq.uiPrivateApi._onComplete @ s3.fine-uploader.js:6107options.onComplete @ s3.fine-uploader.js:2266upload.cleanup @ s3.fine-uploader.js:4566(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:4540(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1126qq.each @ s3.fine-uploader.js:665qq.extend.success @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1125(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1126qq.each @ s3.fine-uploader.js:665qq.extend.success @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1125(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1126qq.each @ s3.fine-uploader.js:665qq.extend.success @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1125xhr.onreadystatechange @ s3.fine-uploader.js:10063
s3.fine-uploader.js:256 [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 500qq.log @ s3.fine-uploader.js:256qq.basePublicApi.log @ s3.fine-uploader.js:1844(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:702onComplete @ s3.fine-uploader.js:3862(anonymous function) @ s3.fine-uploader.js:3970
s3.fine-uploader.js:256 [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Your server indicated failure in its upload success request response for id 0!
```

What's strange is the file is uploaded. Have confirmed this by checking the bucket. It seems as if there is some error with the uploadSuccess: function. I'm using MAMP Pro Locally in case that matters.

Any ideas what may be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 500 error is coming from your signature endpoint, and it is happening when your server attempts to handle Fine Uploader POST "success" request, which indicates that the file is safely in S3. The code attached to that endpoint server-side is failing in some way. You'll need to check your server logs to determine what the specific failure is. Perhaps you are attempting to make a call to S3 server-side as part of this call, and the associated IAM user does not have proper permissions. It could be this, or any number of other issues.

Comment: Thanks Ray, Here is the log which shows a S3 Error: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" options when creating a client or provide an instantiated Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object. Is this a permisison issue? Looks like it may be a configuration issue?? Thanks for your help!!